# Azure Logic Apps Cannot send HTTP request for wns/raw notification

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub, azure-logic-apps

I have a small logic app which is meant to fetch data from somewhere and store it on blob. I then would like to send the URL to all devices via push notification. I wish to send the URL as a raw notification, so on the app/background task, i can do some processiong.

The problem is when i use logic app to create a http POST request to send a notification, i get a 400 error. The same header with authentication and etc, with the payload and URL works fine on a POSTMAN or REST API CLIENT. THe following are the inputs and outputs. Please help. Brain dead already.

This is the input.

```
{
"uri": "https://xxoppoc.servicebus.windows.net/xxopPOC/messages/?api-version=2015-01",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
    "Authorization": "SharedAccessSignature sr=sb%3a%2f%2fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxt%2f&sig=qEnxxxxxxxxxxxx&skn=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature",
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "ServiceBusNotification-Format": "windows",
    "ServiceBusNotification-Tags": "MyTag",
    "X-WNS-Type": "wns/raw"
},
"body": "Some Raw Information. Hello World"
```

}

This is the output:

```
{
"statusCode": 400,
"headers": {
    "transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    "date": "Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:10:41 GMT",
    "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"
},
"body": {
    "$content-type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "$content": "PEVycm9yPjxDb2RlPjQwMDwvQ29kZT48RGV0YWlsPlRoZSBjb250ZW50IHR5cGUgZm9yIGEgJ3ducy9yYXcnIG5vdGlmaWNhdGlvbiBtdXN0IGJlICdhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi9vY3RldC1zdHJlYW0nLlRyYWNraW5nSWQ6NTNmNjhlMGItNDc1MC00ZDRkLWJiNTAtMzJjNTBmOGIyNDk1X0czLFRpbWVTdGFtcDozLzMwLzIwMTYgMjoxMDo0MSBQTTwvRGV0YWlsPjwvRXJyb3I+"
}
```

}

Let me mention again, I got the authentication correct as it works on Advanced REST Client on chrome and POSTMAN. The above logic app also works if i send a wns/toast notification with xml as its content-type. I however need it to be a wns/raw notification. Please help. Thank you

EDIT/PROGRESS

Thanks to MichaelB, We figured out that the content-type is being modified. I sent the request to a different URL to look at the header. The following was observed:
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8

If I use the above Content-Type on POSTMAN. It actually fails as well. So this could be 1 step. Why is Azure Logic Apps adding charset-utf-8 to the end of my content type. Can I stop it?

Comment: Couldn't you send it as XML and extract the URL from that? (its a workaround rather than a fix but it *should* work)

Comment: If I send it as XML. then the WNS-Type part needs to be changed to wns/toast. This would actually show the toast with URL as the message. ITs a requirement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223272.aspx

Comment: That makes sense, apologies then, I have not a lot of knowledge of mobile, that was my troubleshooting brain jumping in :)

Comment: No Problem.. Every suggestion opens up new opportunities to new solutions.

Comment: Do you know that it is specifying the `"X-WNS-Type"` that is breaking it? If you send a message that works in every other way, but only change the type, does that make any difference? (it strikes me as odd that it would choke on the type)

Comment: So if i change the X-WNS-Type to wns/toast, I would also have to change the content-type to application/xml. Both must be changed. With this.. I also now must send a valid body... Which is not a html encoded XML.. IT has tags, and a space for me to put a message. If i run it.. it works immediately.. The notification pops up.. But unfortunately its not what i can work with.. ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107755/discussion-between-michael-b-and-vbaarathi).